# How can I use Mathf.PingPong to scale and rotate an object between max and min?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateAndScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target; // Target to scale
    public Vector3 minScale; // Minimum scale value
    public Vector3 maxScale; // Maximum scale value
    public Vector3 maxRotate;
    public Vector3 minRotate;
    public float speed;

    private float t = 0.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        //if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
        //{
        t += speed * Time.deltaTime;
            target.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(target.localScale, maxScale, t);
            target.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(target.localRotation,
                Quaternion.Euler(maxRotate.x, maxRotate.y, maxRotate.z), t);
       // }
    }
}
```

This will scale and rotate the object to max once. but I want it to get to max and then go back to min and then to max and min nonstop.

Then after it I want to use a key for example C and when pressing once on C it will get to max another press on C it will back to min.

but first I'm not sure how to do it with the pingpong nonstop and then how to do it with the key ?

I added a new global flag to interrupt the Coroutine so if it's true when pressing C in the middle it will change in real time directly to the other direction min or max and if the interrupt flag is false it will use the C key as before. But it's not working it does nothing still I need to wait for it to finish to change to min/max even if interrupt flag is true.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateAndScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target; // Target to scale
    public Vector3 minScale; // Minimum scale value
    public Vector3 maxScale; // Maximum scale value
    public Vector3 maxRotate;
    public Vector3 minRotate;
    public float speed;
    public bool interruptCoroutine = false;

    // Flag for blocking input until one routine is done
    private bool isMoving;

    // Flag for deciding in which direction to go next
    // Via the Inspector set this to the direction it shall initially go towards
    [SerializeField] bool towardsMin;

    private float t = 0.0f;

    void Update()
    {


        if(interruptCoroutine == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
            {
                StopAllCoroutines();
                StartCoroutine(DoMove());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!isMoving && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
            {
                StartCoroutine(DoMove());
            }
        }
    }

    // Once started via a StartCoroutine call this will be executed
    // every frame until the next yield command
    IEnumerator DoMove()
    {
        if (interruptCoroutine == false)
        {
            // Just in case block concurrent routines
            if (isMoving) yield break;

            // Block input
            isMoving = true;
        }

        // Decide if going to Max or min
        var targetRot = Quaternion.Euler(towardsMin ? minRotate : maxRotate);
        var targetScale = towardsMin ? minScale : maxScale;

        // Store Start values
        var startRot = target.localRotation;
        var startScale = target.localScale;

        var duration = 1 / speed;
        var timePassed = 0f;
        while (timePassed < duration)
        {
            t = timePassed / duration;
            // Optional: add ease-in and ease-out
            //t = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, t);

            target.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScale, targetScale, t);
            target.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRot, targetRot, t);

            // Increase the time passed since last frame
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

            // This tells Unity to "pause" the routine here,
            // render this frame and continue from here
            // in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }

        // Just to be sure to end with exact values apply them hard once
        target.localScale = targetScale;
        target.localRotation = targetRot;

        // Invert direction
        towardsMin = !towardsMin;

        if (interruptCoroutine == false)
        {
            // Done -> unlock input
            isMoving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all a general note: This is not how you want to use `Lerp`.

Currently you always start a new interpolation with a growing factor but from the current rotation/scale towards the max values.

So in the next frame the current values will already have moved so the next interpolation uses a different start value etc.

There are basically two use cases how to interpolate:

- Interpolate the current value against a goal using a **constant** factor. This results in a smoothed movement when you have e.g. a camera movement expecting a lot of jitter. This is not what you want to do since this becomes slower and slower in the end probably never reaching the target.
- Interpolate between **constant** start and end point with a factor **growing** from `0` to `1`. This results in a smooth movement within a controlled time. This is more like what you want.

---

[`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) uses a time input and goes forth and back between `0` and a given maximum parameter.

In your case you want to go up to `1` using the speed value as multiplier for the time input.

Like this

```
void Update()
{
    t = Mathf.PingPong(speed * Time.time, 1);
    target.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(target.localScale, maxScale, t);
    target.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(target.localRotation,
        Quaternion.Euler(maxRotate.x, maxRotate.y, maxRotate.z), t);
}
```

---

Then for the one-time key press it gets a bit more complex. I would assume for now you always want to wait until one press "animation" is done before accepting the next key press for going back.

I would use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for this. They work like kind of temporary little `Update` routines but are easier to control and maintain:

```
// Flag for blocking input until one routine is done
bool isMoving;

// Flag for deciding in which direction to go next
// Via the Inspector set this to the direction it shall initially go towards
[SerializeField] bool towardsMin;

void Update()
{
    if(!isMoving && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoMove());
    }
}

// Once started via a StartCoroutine call this will be executed
// every frame until the next yield command
IEnumerator DoMove()
{
    // Just in case block concurrent routines
    if(isMoving) yield break;

    // Block input
    isMoving = true;

    // Decide if going to Max or min
    var targetRot = Quaternion.Euler(towardsMin ? minRotate : maxRotate);
    var targetScale = towardsMin ? minScale : maxScale;

    // Store Start values
    var startRot = target.localRotation;
    var startScale = target.localScale;

    var duration = 1 / speed;  
    var timePassed = 0f;

    while(timePassed < duration)
    {
        t = timePassed / duration;
        // Optional: add ease-in and ease-out
        //t = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, t);

        target.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScale, targetScale, t);
        target.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, targetRotation, t);

        // Increase the time passed since last frame
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

        // This tells Unity to "pause" the routine here,
        // render this frame and continue from here
        // in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // Just to be sure to end with exact values apply them hard once
    target.localScale = targetScale;
    target.localRotation = targetRotation;

    // Invert direction
    towardsMin = !towardsMin;

    // Done -> unlock input
    isMoving = false;
}
```

---

If you rather want to interrupt the current routine and immediately go back instead use

```
// Flag for deciding in which direction to go next
// Via the Inspector set this to the direction it shall initially go towards
// Since the routine inverts this you have to set the initial value to exactly the opposite
// of what you want to be the first direction!
[SerializeField] bool towardsMin;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        StopAllCoroutines(DoMove());
        StartCoroutine(DoMove());
    }
}

// Once started via a StartCoroutine call this will be executed
// every frame until the next yield command
IEnumerator DoMove()
{
    // Invert direction for the next time
    towardsMin = !towardsMin;

    // Decide if going to Max or min
    var targetRot = Quaternion.Euler(towardsMin ? minRotate : maxRotate);
    var targetScale = towardsMin ? minScale : maxScale;

    // Store Start values
    var startRot = target.localRotation;
    var startScale = target.localScale;

    var duration = 1 / speed;  
    var timePassed = 0f;
    while(timePassed < duration)
    {
        t = timePassed / duration;
        // Optional: add ease-in and ease-out
        //t = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, t);

        target.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScale, targetScale, t);
        target.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, targetRotation, t);

        // Increase the time passed since last frame
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

        // This tells Unity to "pause" the routine here,
        // render this frame and continue from here
        // in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // Just to be sure to end with exact values apply them hard once
    target.localScale = targetScale;
    target.localRotation = targetRotation;
}
```

In short: **Get rid of the `isMoving` and all occurrences entirely!**

You will then need to invert the `towardsMin` flag **before** the `while` loop! Thus, you will also need to invert the flag in the Inspector so if you want it first to be moving towards max set this to `true` => Inverted by the coroutine => first time moving towards max values.

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: This is working great. And if I want to add an option also to make that in the middle if I press on C again it will cut the animation and will scale and rotate to min/max ? So once the flag isMoving will block but if not using isMoving I will be able to change directions in the middle.

Comment: Just added it at the bottom ;)

Comment: It's not working the interrupt part. I edited my question with what I tried. I added a new global flag for that so if the flag is true make it possible to interrupt if it's false use it as before wait it to finish.  But it does nothing still I need to wait when pressing on C.

Comment: My bad ... move the inverting of the `towardsMin` flag **before** the `while` loop .. otherwise the direction will never change if the routine is interrupted!

Comment: This is almost working perfect. Now using my code with the global interruptCoroutine and after moving the towardsMin flag before the while loop when running the game I have press on C key twice before it's start moving max or min.  For some reason I need to press twice on C first time running the game to make it start working.

Comment: I found the problem.  The flag towardsMin should be set to true before running the game. Then it's working fine in both cases with the interrupt and without.